# Source code Formatter for Windows Live Writer

Tags: formatting, blogging, code

I have just downloaded the Windows Live Writer software for blogging purposes but it contains nothing for formatting source code.

I have installed many plugins like code snippet, insert code etc. but they all seem so naive. Can someone suggest a good formatting plugin for Windows Live writer or alternatively please suggest some good blogging software with built in support for code highlighting and formatting

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to sharing code snippets in HTML page is using some kind of javascript library that applies the code formatting and highlighting on the client-side. One such library is [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Comment: @Farinha thanks but it does not have the option of line numbers and showing code in box with scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), and there was a good answer there: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2605/373